# Drop Down List Windows Phone 7

Tags: user-interface, controls, windows-phone-7

I'm not able to find a Drop Down list on windows phone 7. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The control?

They don't have one they said it didn't fit with the theme and people should develop without it.

More info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/4ca3f288-aaa2-45a0-b309-f628ba1215a7

Answer (score 13):

Two options you can look at that implement this kind of requirement in a mobile device friendly way.

**List Picker**

[ListPicker? I hardly even know 'er! [A detailed overview of the Windows Phone Toolkit's ListPicker control] - Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx)

**Picker Box**

[Implementing Picker Box functionality on WP7. - Alex Yakhnin's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/12/implementing-picker-box-functionality-on-wp7.aspx)

Alex also outlines the evolution of the Picker Box functionality into List Picker in the Windows Phone Toolkit here.

[Migrate PickerBox and ListPicker to SL Toolkit. - Alex Yakhnin's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/11/07/migrate-pickerbox-and-listpicker-to-sl-toolkit.aspx)

Some people also use ComboBox from the open source Silverlight Toolkit, but be aware it's not styled for metro and some question it's applicability on small screen mobile devices.

Comment: Notice that the last link recommends using the ListPicker in the Silverlight Toolkit.  (Which is discussed by the first link.)  Avoid the interim version mentioned in the middle link.

Comment: Yea, the links and commentary provided was just to give some visibility to the original presentation style and the evolution of what is offered to meet this need.