# Drop down list Control in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: c#, user-interface

I can't seem to find a drop down list (combo box) control for windows phone 7.1. Was it excluded from the sdk or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drop Down List Windows Phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356330/drop-down-list-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such control. You can use `ListPicker` control from [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/). They provide [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit).